# Deploying a module through a feature for web part page

Tags: web-part

I have created a visual web part through visual studio 2010 and it works nicely when I add it to web part page.

I now want to create a custom application page to consume my web part.

I created a new application page called SRPMain.aspx and the solution created it under "Layouts/Certco.SRPWebPart/SRPMain.asxp".  This I understand.

I then converted the application page to a web part page by including a web part zone.

I then created a module to be able to deploy the web part part page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Module Name="SRPModule" >
  <File IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="True" Url="SRPMain.aspx" Name="SRPMain.aspx"        Type="Ghostable" Path="_layouts\Certco.SRPWebPart\SRPMain.aspx"/>
 </Module>
```

When trying to deploy it through a feature I get this error:

```
Error   3   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to instantiate file "SRPMain.aspx" from module "SRPModule": Source path "Features\Certco.SRPWebPart_Feature1\_layouts\Certco.SRPWebPart\SRPMain.aspx" not found.
    0   0   Certco.SRPWebPart
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find the .aspx file to deploy through the feature.  How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPartZones are not supported in Application pages.

But your web aprt is "just" a web control so you can include directly into an application page.

You can also make the page a site page and deploy it using a Module as you've started to. But then the aspx file should be inside your feature folder and the Path attribute is relative to that.

Comment: How do I make the page a site page?

Comment: You're already a long way towards it you just need to move SRPMain.aspx to the folder where you have the Elements.xml file with the `<Module>` element , change the Path to just "SRPMain.aspx" and change SRPMain.aspx to inherit from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage`

Comment: I did above.  I moved the SRPMain.aspx page under the module and my Elements.xml changed to:      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="SRPModule"  >
   
  <File Path="SRPModule\SRPMain.aspx" Url="SRPModule/SRPMain.aspx" />
<File Path="SRPChange.aspx" Url="SRPModule/SRPChange.aspx" />   .  

</Module>
</Elements>  It still errors on feature activation.

Comment: I was able to get it deployed thank you. However, where is the page deployed?  I only see the module under site pages and not the actual page.

Comment: It should be SITEURL/SRPModule/SRPMain.aspx thats what yor specify in Url. If you want it in SitePages then you need to change the Url and specify Type="GhostabeInLibrary"

Comment: please mark this response as answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer :

-> Choose Show all files.

-> Open file in your module directory with extension `.spdata`

-> Look at `<ProjectItemFile>` of your page.

-> Edit **Source** and **Target** attributes.